# jQuery equivalent to "getElementsByName"

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the correct jquery syntax for a `getElementsByName` call?

Here is my javascript code:

```
var test = document.getElementsByName(tableName)[0];
```

using this is returning a different value:

```
var test = $("[name=tableName]");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you give an example of the results you're getting and how they're different?

Answer (score 29):

Use quotes around the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('[name="somenamehere"]');
```

If you need to use a variable within a selector, you need to use string concatenation to get the value of the variable:

```
$('[name="' + tableName + '"]');
```

---

Typically one should avoid using the `[name]` attribute in favor of the `[id]` attribute, because selection would be simpler as:

```
$('#someidhere');
-or-
$('#' + tableID);
```

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, I distinctly remember running into issues with quotes on attribute selectors with an older version of jQuery. It's quite possible I'm misremembering.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, I think I had it backwards, i think the older versions of jQuery *only* supported quoted attribute values, and that the newer versions support quoted or unquoted attribute values.

Comment: No, the new versions require quotes. That is clear. Quotes were optional in older versions. My guess is that omitting quotes led to issues, which is why they are required now.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, without going into too much discussion [jQuery 1.7.1 supports unquoted attributes](http://jsfiddle.net/m6DmE/)...I've redacted the statement anyway.

Comment: The jQuery documentation states: "*Attribute values in selector expressions **must** be surrounded by quotation marks.*", [read here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/). However, the documentation also states that the value can be "*an unquoted single word*", [read here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Answer (score 8):

Remove the index from the first statement

These are equal.

```
var test = document.getElementsByName(tableName);
var test = $("[name=tableName]");
```

Comment: how can i access the same index [0] in jquery?

Comment: $("[name=tableName]").get(0);

Comment: @westo Either is fine, but shorter is better `:)`

Comment: Further to this though, they are not exactly the same. Using get() provides additional functionality. e.g. The ability to put a negative values to select from the end of the array.

Answer (score 2):

`"[name=tableName]"` is bad syntax in 2 ways.  First, you should put your name in quotes, so it should be `"[name='tableName']"` and second, in the first case, you're using a variable and in the second, a string, so in reality it shoudl be `"[name='" + tableName + "']"`

good call also on the fact that you have an index on your `getelementsbyname()` call, if you select item `[0]` then it will only return one item.

Comment: how can i return the same index [0] in a jquery syntax?

Comment: `$("[name='" + tableName + "']").first();`

Answer (score 1):

Interesting to know that jquery is a LOT slower than the native method here.
See the jsPrefs test : http://jsperf.com/getelementsbyname-vs-jquery-selektor/4

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get a element value use this code:

```
var test1 = $("[name='tableName']").val();
alert(test1);
```

These are equal to get value of specific index[]:

**For same index [0]**

```
var test2 = $("[name='arryname[]']")[0];
alert(test2.value);

var test3 = $("[name='arryname[]']").get([0]);
alert(test3.value);
```